# React Native Expo (Android) Localization - Defaults To 92 (All?) Localizations

Tags: android, react-native, localization, expo

I've written an app for the Google Play Store using React Native / Expo. Upon building and submitting my app, it appears that it's listed as supporting 92 (all?) localizations even though I haven't set up any localizations and am only trying to support `en-US`.

I know Expo includes many permissions by default, so I thought it would be similar to fixing that (specifying the supported languages in `app.json` or something similar). After spending a couple hours searching and combing through their documentation, however, I've only been able to find references to adding localizations to the app, not removing them. Not really sure how to solve this problem.

I'm fairly new to React Native and Android in general, so hoping I'm just missing something simple.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: i have the exact same Q & couldn't find any answers that does not involve changing Native code/config

Comment: I haven't been able to find any workarounds since posting this, myself. Decided to just live with it for now.

Glad to hear I'm not the only one with the issue, though lol. Let me know if you find any fixes, please! I'll do the same.

Comment: yeah, I asked this Q on Expo forum earlier, hopefully someone may have an answer for us